# Underlying DataStructure of Java PriorityQueue

Tags: java, collections, queue, heap, priority-queue

Referencing from the book [Java: The Complete Reference](https://www.amazon.in/Java-Complete-Reference-Herbert-Schildt/dp/9339212096), "Queue" interface extend "Collection" interface. Also, "PriorityQueue" extends "AbstractQueue" class and implements "Queue" interface.

Also, as per lots of articles over Internet, Heaps provides the most efficient Priority Queue implementation considering both Insert and Remove in O(logn). And being complete binary tree, heaps can be implemented simply on an array/list.

My question is, If heaps are efficient for Priority Queues, than why `PriorityQueue` uses a `Queue` interface? Why it's not using `List` interface? Otherwise, what is the underlying concept/idea of the implementation, providing time complexity same(or better) as heaps?

Comment: Those are totally different interfaces. A [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) is wlog. unorderend and allows insertion and deletion at random indices. [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html)s are ordered and only provide methods to add elements such that the queue-property is not violated and to peek &pop the topmost element.

Comment: Because it implements a queue, which is something you add to the end of and take from the beginning of, and not a list, which is something you iterate over, add and remove in the middle of, etc. There is no reason why the interface needs to reflect the underlying implementation.

Comment: You should try to understand the difference between *implementing* an interface and *internally using* a data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces are "contracts" which ensure that classes  implementing them will provide certain "behavior" - methods.

So client code (code that will make use of `PriorityQueue` for example) will have guarantees that this class will have behavior that may be expected only from `Queue` implementation.

In other words:

`List` interface has methods that are useful to work with lists.

`Queue` interface has methods that are useful for work with queues.

`PriorityQueue` that implements methods of a `List` interface just won't be comfortable to work with.

And vice versa, imagine `ArrayList` that implements `Queue` interface - it will be chaos to work with such thing.

More related to your question:
There may be multiple implementations of `Queue` interface - on array, on `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` with different time complexity and so on, but all of them will provide same set of methods of `Queue` interface.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `PriorityQueue` is just a `Queue` with the Heapify technique to guarantee good performance during insertion/deletion.

Heap means Heapify technique

Why `PriorityQueue` uses the Heapify technique?

- Heapifying is a method for inserting/deleting with the worst case of *O(log<sub>2</sub> N)*

What is the inheritance hierarchy of `PriorityQueue`?

```java
public class PriorityQueue<E> extends AbstractQueue<E> {}
```

```java
public abstract class AbstractQueue<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> {}
```

```java
public abstract class AbstractCollection<E> implements Collection<E> {}
```

What is the inheritance hierarchy of `List`?

```java
public interface List<E> extends Collection<E> {}
```

Why the `PriorityQueue` does not extend the `List` interface?

Because the `List` interface provides operations not defined or needed to the `PriroityQueue` like `get(index)`, and the implementation just `add()` and `poll()` which similar to the queue mechanism which is insertion to the tail and poll from the head, and not sequential insertion like `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` which are extending the `List` interface. And no ability to get the values with index position.

What is the difference between `PriorityQueue` and `Queue`?

`PriorityQueue` uses the "Heapify" technique and can be Min PQ or Max PQ and you can simply define that when you declare the constructor of the `PriorityQueue`, while the `Queue` just adds the values to the tail and poll from the head.

What are the benefits to use `PriorityQueue`?

The big benefit is you can define Min PQ or Max PQ and get the elements in sorting order ascending or descending with time complexity *O(log<sub>2</sub> N)*, and this important for many applications like finding the shortest path, collision of particles detection, etc.